# List branches of a git remote repo without cloning it

Tags: java, jgit

I was wondering hows it would be possible to list all the branches of a remote Git repo with jgit but without cloning it.

While going through the jgit's javadoc, I found the [ListBranchCommand](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/ListBranchCommand.html) but that only seem to work with an already opened Repository object. But I was not able to find how to create a Repository object over HTTP without cloning it in local.

Is it possible ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `LsRemoteCommand` to list the branches of a remote repository. To obtain the command, use either

```
Git.wrap(repo).lsRemote()
```

or

```
Git.lsRemoteRepository()
```

The statically created `LsRemoteCommand` has its limitations. For certain transport protocols, a local repository is necessary to obtain configuration settings. Therefore I usually create an empty temporary local repository with `Git.init()` and then use the first approach.

If you want to avoid creating the extra repository, you can test with `Transport.open()` if it succeeds without a repository. It throws a `NotSupportedException` otherwise.

Comment: Doesn't cloning the repo to local represent a problem when the distant repo is very large ?

Comment: @user3459089: There is no need to clone the remote repository. Just an empty local repository (as can be created with `Git.init()`) is necessary for certain transport protocols to work.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. I have to admit that I never did researches in that way since it seemed pretty logic to me that you had to clone the repo to do these sort of commands.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, never mind, after hours searching for the answer, I find it right before asking it there...

So, the answer is in the [CookBook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ListRemoteRepository.java) :

```
Collection<Ref> refs = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
            .setHeads(true)
            .setTags(true)
            .setRemote(REMOTE_URL)
            .call();
```