# How to do a "git clone --mirror" in JGit?

Tags: git, clone, git-clone, jgit

Reading the [documentation](https://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/site/3.7.0.201502260915-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CloneCommand.html) it seems like there is no explicit method to do a `git clone --mirror` in JGit.

In case of `git push` there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294554/how-to-use-jgit-to-do-equivalent-of-git-push-mirror). I was wondering if there is any for `git clone` as well. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is, that when using `--mirror`, all refs are copied as-is. To simulate this behaviour with JGit, initialize a bare repository and configure the remote repository.

Now use the `FetchCommand` to transfer all refs from the remote repository. Make sure to specify the ref-specs to include all relevant refs like heads, tags, notes, etc.

```java
Git git = Git.init().setBare(true).setGitDir(...).call()
git.remoteAdd().setName("origin").setUri(new URIish("URL/to/mirror/source")).call();
git.fetch().setRemote("origin").setRefSpecs("+refs/*:refs/*").call();
```